# Better way to display dot (5*5) in UICollectionViewCell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I just want to know that which is the best and better way to draw/display dot in UICollectionViewCell.

[image]

I want to display dots for image/video either that image/video is shared on Social media or not. In above image, dark blue dot indicates that the image/video is shared in Facebook and light blue dot for Twitter shared.

So my question is, which is better way to achieve that?

1. Add UIView on cell and fill color and cornerRadius.
2. Make 1x,2x,3x images and display in cell with UIImageView.
3. Using CAShapeLayer() and UIBezierPath().

or any other way?

Which is best and how related to memory and performance?

Comment: Go with 1st. It will help in view rendering, CAShapeLayer() and UIBezierPath() will take more time than UIView. Using image will increase app size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass a `UICollectionViewCell` and add a `UIView` to it with `layer.cornerRadius` set as well as background colour. This approach could be implemented completely programmatically or with a xib.

Actually if you want to dynamically set the dot size you can add constraints separately for each size class.

`CAShapeLayer` is quite memory intensive in comparison. The image view approach also unnecessary increases file size.